# Error Handling : Capture error objects in catch block

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling

I have the below Error Model.

```
enum MyErrorType: ErrorType
{
    case RequestFormationError(errorDomain : ARSErrorDomain)
    case NetworkError(errorDomain : ARSErrorDomain)

    case FileNameError(errorDomain : ARSErrorDomain)
    case FileNotFoundError(errorDomain : ARSErrorDomain)

    case ValidationError(errorDomain : ARSErrorDomain)
}

class MyErrorDomain: NSObject
{
    var errorMessage : String?
    //var errorCode : String?

    convenience init(errorMessage: String)
    {
        self.init()

        self.errorMessage = errorMessage
    }
}
```

Whenever an error happens in the code, i pass it to the calling function. My problem is how do i access the MyErrorDomain in the catch block? Can anyone let me know the syntax?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use following syntax:

```
do {
    ....
} catch MyErrorType.RequestFormationError(let errorDomain) {
    print(errorDomain)
}
```

It is described [in docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html).

Comment: Without specifying RequestFormationError, can i just access errorDomain, by creating a super class or some similar implementation. Because for a particular case i am not worried about the errorType but only the errorDomain.

Comment: I think i need to move the enum inside errorDomain for a generic access of errorDomain. Right?